# Grunt grunt-postcss Autoprefixer not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, postcss, autoprefixer

I've jumped into a non-profit open source project and wanted to help out a little bit but I'm unfamiliar with Grunt. I did some research and can't figure out why the configuration isn't working.

Here's the plugin I'm trying to use. It allows applying several postprocessors but I just need Autoprefixer for now:
https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss

The configuration:

- `Gruntfile.js` http://pastebin.com/4Ud0sa1W
- `grunt/concurrent.js` http://pastebin.com/Satr1wSK
- `grunt/sass.js` http://pastebin.com/rc6evWas
- `grunt/watch.js` http://pastebin.com/eGBpFSLs

The task gets executed without a problem:

```
laptop:website lextoc$ grunt sass:postcss
Running "sass:postcss" (sass) task

Done.
```

But the css file doesn't get the required vendor prefixes, I'm using `display: flex` to check if it works.

The original project (I forked it) can be found here:
https://github.com/faforever/website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work successfully...

#### Revert to the original files

1. Firstly, I recommend that you revert all code samples, (i.e. those that you provided a *pastebin* for), to the original code versions that can be found in the github repo that you forked*. Namely the following files:

   1. [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/FAForever/website/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)
   2. [grunt/concurrent.js](https://github.com/FAForever/website/blob/master/grunt/concurrent.js)
   3. [grunt/sass.js](https://github.com/FAForever/website/blob/master/grunt/sass.js)
   4. [grunt/watch.js](https://github.com/FAForever/website/blob/master/grunt/watch.js)

** Reverting to the original versions will just make it easier to carry out the following steps.*

---

#### Task setup for *postcss*

2. Create a new file named ***postcss.js*** and save it to the folder named ***grunt*** in the project directory. *(As many of the other Tasks for the project exist as separate `.js` files we'll do the same for this new one too)*.

The content of ***postcss.js*** should be as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
    prefix: {
        options: {
            processors: [
                require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: ['last 8 versions', 'ie 9'] })
            ]
        },
         src: './public/styles/css/*.css'
    }
};
```

---

#### Gruntfile.js

3. Next, update the existing registered task named ***prod*** in `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

```js
// ...
grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    'sass:dist',
    'postcss:prefix',
    'concat:js',
    'uglify:dist'
]);
// ...
```

**Note** the addition of `'postcss:prefix'` in the [TaskList](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) array. Also, it's ***not*** necessary to add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');` because the tasks get loaded via the line reading `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`.

---

#### Update *watch.js*

4. The task named `sass` in the ***watch.js*** file, found in the ***grunt*** folder, should be updated as follows:

```js
// ...
sass: {
    files: ['public/styles/**/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass:dev', 'postcss:prefix']
},
// ...
```

**Note** the addition of `'postcss:prefix'` added to the `tasks` array. This will ensure the prefixes are applied after the `.scss` files have been converted to `.css`.

---

#### Additional notes:

1. You may also need to add [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) to your package too:

`$ npm install autoprefixer --save-dev`

2. Now when you run either `$ grunt serve` *(...and save any edits to the `.scss` files)* or `$ grunt prod` the resultant `.css` files will include the required vendor prefixes.
3. Running `$ grunt sass:postcss` is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same proble. You try this:

```
postcss: {
    options: {
      processors: [
        require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 8 versions', 'ie 9']})
      ]
    },
    src: 'public/styles/css/*.css'
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Fatal error: Path must be a string. Received undefined`.